# How to create a form for a petition?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, database

**I need to create a form for a petition.**

The form needs to have a **Name field[Text input]**, **Email field[Text input]** and **another field that would be a String of letters and numbers.**

After the user fills in the Text input fields, I need to have a database that saves that data from the form somewhere, so I need to have a list of People[maybe an Array?] that have signed the petition[that is completed the fields and pressed the submit button]

Where do I get started? What do I google for to learn how to create this myself
[I know how to add the Text input from HTML, I can customize them with CSS. That's easy, but how do I make the form submit what the user inputs[Name and Email and the random string] in some database? or something that saves all the data and pushes it into an array ?

Can I find something already made that I can customize ?

I am not a programmer, but I do have programming knowledge with ActionScript3, HTML/CSS and a little bit of Java Script.

Help! THX

Comment: You're essentially asking for a tutorial on server side web programming. From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-PHP-MySQL-Professional-Development/dp/1430231149/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1335865349&sr=8-11) that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* (link to book should not be considered an endorsement, it was the first one I found when searching)

Comment: Have you tried something like http://www.change.org/petition ? Maybe that's something for you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad. You can find a lot of tutorials on the Internet. If you have learnt how it works, and you have questions, we are happy to help. You could also google `online petition` I'm sure there is a great number of sites that let you create petitions without having to program your own.

Comment: Flavius, try and accept answers to questions and people are more likely to help out.

Comment: People, calm down, just be broad like the question is, look into: That, that and that, with those 3 you can create a simple form that saves the data somewhere.  [That is what I am looking for :)]

Comment: For that you can google, what set-up do you have - where does it need to run, it will dictate possible programming languages

Comment: `Where do I get started?` Well, firstly, navigate to google.com (or any search engine you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to learn some form or programming language for that - PHP, ASP etc. so I suppose it depends on the time-scales for the project. In the interest of speed and accuracy for my dissertation I used an online service, I can build it but didn't have the time. There are lots:

http://wufoo.com/
http://www.formstack.com/